# Error in matchin @string value in .xlm layout

Tags: android, xml, string, android-studio

I created a text box, associated to him his string value and all goes well. Later I added a new text box and associated him another string. The problem is that even the first text box took the second string.

Here the xml code:

```
<TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/istruzioni"
            android:id="@+id/istruzioni" />
    </TableRow>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:weightSum="1">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:text="@string/inserimentoCodice"
            android:id="@+id/inserimentoCodice"
            android:layout_gravity="left" />[...]
```

The two string are `istruzioni` and `inserimentoCodice` .

Here my `strings.xml` file

```
<string name="app_name">Controllore</string>
<string name="controlla">Controlla corsa</string>
<string name="nuova">Nuova corsa</string>
<string name="quit">Quit</string>
<string name="istruzioni">Dopo aver inserito il codice del documento di identità dell'utente, verrà visualizzata l'ultima convalida, e confermata la sua eventuale validità</string>
<string name="inserimentoCodice">Inserire codice documento:</string>
```

If in the first file I put the mouse over the `inserimentoCodice` line, I get this:

[image]

Why Android studio decides to overwrite another string?

I'm working on ubuntu 13.10 with Android studio

Comment: do you have issues at runtime or do you have issues with the AndroidStudio's graphical editor?

Comment: in the graphical editor

Comment: then you should asked to the AndroidStudio team. The question is off topic

Comment: ok, sorry. I thought that maybe it could be a my error, so I posted it here.

Comment: Android studio is actualy under develop and bug fixing.
Probably you have found a bug...report it here:

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/list?can=2&q=&colspec=ID+Type+Status+Owner+Summary+Stars&cells=tiles